What materials support longitudinal versus transverse electromagnetic waves?
Background:
In electrodynamics, one examines the Maxwell equations and analyzes the solutions to discover the form of electromagnetic waves. If we are looking at electromagnetic waves in materials, we examine the macroscopic Maxwell equations and look for solutions.
Say that we allow our material to be characterized by a permittivity value $\epsilon(\omega)$, which has both real and imaginary parts. Then, the macroscopic Maxwell equations give us $$i k \cdot D_{\omega} = i\epsilon(\omega) k \cdot E_{\omega} = 0 \implies k \perp E_{\omega}$$ if $\epsilon(\omega) \neq 0$ and $$i k \cdot B = 0 \implies k \perp B_{\omega}.$$ From this, we can see that only transverse waves are permitted in this case.
However, we can also see that if we allow $\epsilon(\omega) = 0$, then we can have longitudinal modes.
In my electrodynamics course, we treat these longitudinal modes in the content on "Electromagnetic Wave Propagation in Conductors", whereas the transverse modes are treated in "Electromagnetic Waves in Dielectrics".
Question:
Now, my question is what does this distinction in allowed modes have to do with dielectric versus conducting materials? It would seem that we could have $\epsilon(\omega) = 0$ in both conductors and dielectrics. This would permit longitudinal and transverse waves in both cases.
Expectations:
I have conflicting thoughts influencing my expectations.

I'd actually expect conductors to have a large $\epsilon$ value, not zero. However, I believe it is not as simple as assessing if $\epsilon(\omega)$ is large or small -- we also need to consider how the real and complex components compare in size.
We know that $\epsilon(\omega) = 1 - \frac{\omega^2_p}{\omega^2}$, where $\omega_p = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi ne^2}{m}}$ is the plasma frequency. I have only seem the plasma frequency discussed alongside conductors, so this would suggest that the longitudinal modes are specific to conductors for some reason.


even ether can "support" longitudinal components as it is the natural mode of propagation in axially homogeneous metallic pipes even if it is filled with any variable cross section dielectric material, see TE, TM, qTE, qTM modes and their relatives.

Your question is totally missing the conductivity term coming from Ohm's Law $\vec J=\sigma\vec E$, the consequence of which is the complexification of your $\varepsilon$ function, and then things can be a lot more complicated than you think it has to be. On top of that, you can have, as hyportnex said, non-TEM waves in "free space" inside a waveguide.
